# Stored Procedure insert and update statements working but rows affected is -1?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, ado.net

I am working on a program that can add sponsors via a VB program. My stored procedures for adding and updating a sponsor are working when I test them in SQL, but both are throwing an error because the rows affected is coming back -1. When I look at my database, the insert / update DID work, though. Can anyone help me figure out why the rows affected is coming back -1 if the insert worked?

It's bringing back -1 for both stored procedures. Here's the code for adding a sponsor:

SQL:

```sql
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddSponsor
    @intSponsorID AS INTEGER OUTPUT
   ,@strFirstName AS VARCHAR(50)
   ,@strLastName AS VARCHAR(50)
   ,@strStreetAddress AS VARCHAR(50)
   ,@strCity AS VARCHAR(50)
   ,@strState AS VARCHAR(50)
   ,@strZip AS VARCHAR(50)
   ,@strPhoneNumber AS VARCHAR(50)
   ,@strEmail AS VARCHAR(50)

AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON      --Report only errors
SET XACT_ABORT ON   --Terminate and rollback transaction on error

BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO TSponsors WITH (TABLOCKX) (strFirstName, strLastName, strStreetAddress, strCity, strState, strZip, strPhoneNumber, strEmail)
    VALUES               (@strFirstName, @strLastName, @strStreetAddress, @strCity, @strState, @strZip, @strPhoneNumber, @strEmail)

    SELECT @intSponsorID = MAX(intSponsorID) FROM TSponsors

COMMIT TRANSACTION

GO
```

VB CODE:

```vb
Private Sub AddSponsor(ByVal strFirstName As String, ByVal strLastName As String, ByVal strAddress As String, ByVal strCity As String, ByVal strState As String, ByVal strZip As String, ByVal strPhoneNumber As String, ByVal strEmail As String)
    Dim intRowsAffected As Integer
    Dim cmdAddSponsor As New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
    Dim intPKID As Integer

    Try
        'Open DB
        If OpenDatabaseConnectionSQLServer() = False Then

            ' No, warn the user ...
            MessageBox.Show(Me, "Database connection error." & vbNewLine &
                                "The application will now close.",
                                Me.Text + " Error",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

            ' and close the form/application
            Me.Close()
        End If

        'Text to call stored procedure
        cmdAddSponsor.CommandText = "EXECUTE uspAddSponsor '" & intPKID & "','" & strFirstName & "','" & strLastName & "','" & strAddress & "','" & strCity & "','" & strState & "','" & strZip & "','" & strPhoneNumber & "','" & strEmail & "'"
        cmdAddSponsor.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        'Call stored procedure which will insert the record
        cmdAddSponsor = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(cmdAddSponsor.CommandText, m_conAdministrator)

        'This return is the # of rows affected
        intRowsAffected = cmdAddSponsor.ExecuteNonQuery()

        'Close DB
        CloseDatabaseConnection()

        'Let user know what happened
        If intRowsAffected > 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Sponsor successfully added")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Sponsor not added. Error")
        End If

        Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See that `SET NOCOUNT ON`? It means "don't return the count of rows affected". It's a common optimization (it saves an extra network roundtrip) but obviously no good if you *do* want the number of rows affected. Normally, what you'd do is assume the sproc worked correctly if it didn't generate an error (which would work fine in this case, especially since it's using `XACT_ABORT ON` *and* there's an output parameter).

Comment: That makes sense, thanks so much!

Comment: @jenniferjonas I would highly recommend using proper SqlParameter objects to pass your parameters to your stored procedure instead of building a dynamic string. Parameters protect you from injection, ensure the datatype is correct and more.

Comment: Stop using table hints until you have much more experience, understand their effect, and have identified a good reason to use them. Presumably your table has an identity column  - if so, it is far better to use an output clause or `scope_identity()` to retrieve the value generated for your row.

Comment: The following may help, [SP Insert](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/SqlServerStoredProceduresVisualBasic/blob/master/DatabaseScripts.sql#L203) , [back end code](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/SqlServerStoredProceduresVisualBasic/blob/master/DataOperations_vb/BackendOperations.vb#L173). See also [TechNet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53391.sql-server-stored-procedures-for-vb-net-windows-forms.aspx)

Comment: @DaleK i'm not, can you please fill me in?

Comment: If this is Sql Server why are you using OleDb provider?

Answer (score 5):

As per the [Official Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

> When SET NOCOUNT ON is set on the connection (before or as part of executing the command, or as part of a trigger initiated by the execution of the command) the rows affected by individual statements stop contributing to the count of rows affected that is returned by this method.

I suggest using the return value of the SP to indicate whether the SP worked or not as that it is its intended purpose - since you aren't actually using the number of rows affected for anything else.